# what is the clojure way to do things

Tags: clojure

As part of a larger program, I'm testing a function that will turn a string of days on which a class occurs (such as "MWF") into a list of seven numbers: (1 0 1 0 1 0 0).
I first translate"TH" (Thursday) to "R" and "SU" (Sunday) to "N" to make things a bit easier.

I came up with the following code:

```
(defn days-number-maker
  "Recursively compare first item in days of week with
first item in string of days. If matching, add a 1,
else add a zero to the result"
  [all-days day-string result]
  (if (empty? all-days) (reverse result)
    (if (= (first all-days) (first day-string))
      (recur (rest all-days)(rest day-string) (conj result 1))
      (recur (rest all-days) day-string (conj result 0)))))

(defn days-to-numbers
  "Change string like MTTH to (1 1 0 1 0 0 0)"
  [day-string]
  (let [days (clojure.string/replace
               (clojure.string/replace day-string #"TH" "R") #"SU" "N")]
    (days-number-maker "MTWRFSN" days (list))))
```

The good news: the code works. The bad news: I'm convinced I'm doing it wrong, in the moral purity sense of the word. Something inside of me says, "You could have just used (map...) to do this the *right* way," but I can't see how to do it with (map). So, my two questions are:

1) Is there such a thing as "the Clojure way," and if so,
2) How can I rewrite the code to be more Clojure-ish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map and sets

Using map and sets:

```
(defn days-number-maker
  [all-days day-string]
  (let [day-set (set day-string)]
    (map (fn [day]
           (if (day-set day)
             1
             0))
         all-days)))

(defn days-to-numbers
  "Change string like MTTH to (1 1 0 1 0 0 0)"
  [day-string]
  (let [days (clojure.string/replace
               (clojure.string/replace day-string #"TH" "R") #"SU" "N")]
    (days-number-maker "MTWRFSN" days)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it a bit more succinctly:

```
(defn days-to-numbers
  "Change string like MTTH to (1 1 0 1 0 0 0)"
  [week-string]
  (let [char-set (set (clojure.string/replace
                        (clojure.string/replace week-string "TH" "R") "SU" "N"))]
    (map #(if (char-set %) 1 0)
         "MTWRFSN")))
```

Tests:

```
=> (days-to-numbers "")
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
=> (days-to-numbers "MTWTHFSSU")
(1 1 1 1 1 1 1)
=> (days-to-numbers "MTHSU")
(1 0 0 1 0 0 1)
=> (days-to-numbers "FM")
(1 0 0 0 1 0 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from [@TheQuickBrownFox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25992528/1562315) ...

- You don't need to recode `"TH"` and `"SU"`: the second letters will
  do.
- Use `false` or `nil` instead of `0`, so that you can apply logical tests directly.
- Return the result as a vector, as you're quite likely to want to
  index into it.

Giving ...

```
(defn days-to-numbers [ds]
  (let [dns (->> ds
             (partition-all 2 1)
             (remove #{[\S \U] [\T \H]})
             (map first)
             set)]
    (mapv dns "MTWHFSU")))
```

For example,

```
(days-to-numbers "MTTH")
;[\M \T nil \H nil nil nil]
```

Though the function is mis-named, as the elements are logical values, not numbers.

---

I'd prefer to return the *set* of day numbers:

```
(def day-index (into {} (map-indexed (fn [x y] [y x]) "MTWHFSU")))
;{\M 0, \T 1, \W 2, \H 3, \F 4, \S 5, \U 6}

(defn day-numbers [ds]
  (->> ds
       (partition-all 2 1)
       (remove #{[\S \U] [\T \H]})
       (map (comp day-index first))
       set))
```

For example,

```
(day-numbers "MTTH")
;#{0 1 3}
```